# MySQL how to find urls in a string and remove a character from them?

Tags: mysql, string, replace

I have an issue with my website-database, in my DB I have articles saved and my website fetches them. My issue is with URLs inside the article because when I wrote those articles I forgot to remove apostrophes from URLs.. so the article is a text like this.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Bona autem corporis huic sunt, quod posterius posui, similiora. Cur id non ita fit?

Check out <a href="www.example.com/this-is-an-example-l'oro.html">this is an example l'oro</a>
```

So I'd like to remove the apostrophe only from URLs.

```
BEFORE:
<a href="www.example.com/this-is-an-example-l'oro.html">this is an example l'oro</a>

AFTER:
<a href="www.example.com/this-is-an-example-loro.html">this is an example l'oro</a>
```

My issue is that the apostrophe must be removed only from Urls inside  tag and not in the text from the article.

I'd like to fix it using a mysql query if it's possible

Comment: Formulate the criteria which allows 100% define what is URL in your case. Substring before (for example, `'<a href="'`), substring after (for example. `'">'`), pattern in... If URL contains more than one `'` - does all of them must be removed? Does the value contains strictly one URL? 0 or 1? any amount?

Comment: @Akina Yes, all ```'``` must be removed from URL. All urls are inside ```<a href="URL">``` tag, also they are all from the same domain, so example.com is common in all urls. There are 2 urls per article.

Comment: What is precise MySQL version? What is maximal URLs per value amount? May I assume that the article text contains strictly 4 `"` chars per value?

Comment: @Akina it says  10.2.34-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server, sometimes there are more ```"``` than 4 in the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, 
                1 level, 
                CASE WHEN LOCATE('"', article)
                     THEN SUBSTRING(article FROM 1 FOR LOCATE('"', article))
                     ELSE article END chunk,
                CASE WHEN LOCATE('"', article)
                     THEN SUBSTRING(article FROM 1 + LOCATE('"', article))
                     ELSE '' END slack
         FROM test 
        UNION ALL
         SELECT id, 
                1 + level, 
                CASE WHEN LOCATE('"', slack)
                     THEN SUBSTRING(slack FROM 1 FOR LOCATE('"', slack))
                     ELSE slack END,
                CASE WHEN LOCATE('"', slack)
                     THEN SUBSTRING(slack FROM 1 + LOCATE('"', slack))
                     ELSE '' END 
         FROM cte 
         WHERE TRIM(slack) != '' )
SELECT id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN LOCATE('www.example.com', chunk)
                         THEN REPLACE(chunk, '\'', '')
                         ELSE chunk END ORDER BY level SEPARATOR '') article
FROM cte
GROUP BY id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=95d2655c5ea6e5a2b74e466c9a4948b7)

In recursive CTE the value is divided on chunks by d-quote chars. Then href links are detected by domain (`'www.example.com'`) substring, and quote chars are removed. Finally the value is reconstructed back.

Comment: Thank you, it runs fine and it shows the fields with changes, but when I refresh and check the articles looks like it doesn't update articles

Comment: @vamp *looks like it doesn't update articles* Of course.. this is SELECT. If you need to update then join this query to another table copy by `id` and update.